# Hover image and glows [Bootstrap]

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How would I make the image glow when hover? I would like to use white-color.

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com"><img src="resources/img/email.png"  class="img-circle"></a>
```

image:

`https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx0kH.png`

Can't post link. So, I would like to make it glow (inside), thanks. Any help would be great

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you mean by 'glow'? Like do you want the image to change or just the border to glow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is accomplished with two versions of the same image (use of photo editing tools). Then use this code:

```
<img src="URL of darker image here"
         onmouseover="this.src='URL of lighter image';"
         onmouseout="this.src='URL of darker image here';">
</img>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give glow at the borders using

```
img:hover
{
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #ddd;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #ddd;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #ddd;
}
```

You can choose the color you want according to your requirements.
you can also visit http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ilqnb
or http://css3generator.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use box-shadow withInset property

> .shadow { -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000; -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000; box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000; }